# Adding LDAP Attributes to Third Party Claims Provider Trust Claims

Tags: active-directory, saml, adfs, claims-based-identity, claims-authentication

1. I have the default SAML 2.0 Claims Provider configured on ADFS. Let's call it DefaultProvider. It requires username and password.
2. I have two SAML 2.0 Relying Parties configured that are working with the DefaultProvider. I'm able to assert LDAP attributes from the DefaultProvider to these Relying Parties and authenticate successfully.
3. I've imported a second SAML 2.0 Claims Provider. Let's call it Provider2.
4. I'm able to configure the Claims Allowances for Provider2 and the Translation Rules for Provider2 using attributes from Provider2. I'm able to log into my two Relying Parties from Provider2 and receive the attributes that Provider2 had sent in the assertion.

For item 4, is it possible to enhance the the claims sent to the two Relying Parties with not only attributes from Provider2 assertions but also from local LDAP attributes from my local ADFS/AD and add those attributes to the assertions sent to the two Relying Parties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this requires a custom rule to query AD. This article explains the exact process:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/pinch-perfect/querying-attributes-from-active-directory-using-adfs-with-a-3rd-party-identity-provider